# Showing that the isomorphism between $W\otimes V^*$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(V, W)$ is an equivalence of representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

It is known that if $V, W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces with $V^*$ being the dual of $V$, then the map $f:W\otimes V^*\to \mathrm{Hom}(V, W), f(w\otimes v^*)(v) = v^*(v)w, \forall v \in V$ defines an isomorphism. Suppose that $G$ is a group and $\rho_1:G\to \mathrm{Aut}(V), \rho_2:G\to \mathrm{Aut}(W)$ are two representations of $G$. I'm trying to show that at some $w \otimes \overline{v}^* \in W\otimes V^*$, $f(w\otimes \overline{v}^*)$ is an equivalence of representations, i.e. a bijective intertwining map: $\rho_2(g) \circ f(w\otimes \overline{v}^*) = f(w\otimes \overline{v}^*)\circ \rho_1(g)$.

But when I take any $v \in V, g \in G$, I get that $(\rho_2(g)\circ f(w\otimes \overline{v}^*))(v) = \rho_2(g)(\overline{v}^*(v)w) = \overline{v}^*(v)\rho_2(g)(w)$, and $(f(w\otimes \overline{v}^*)\circ \rho_1(g))(v) = \overline{v}^*(\rho_1(g)v)w$, by linearity of representations. But I'm not sure how I should conclude from here that $\rho_2(g)(\overline{v}^*(v)w) = \overline{v}^*(\rho_1(g)v)w$

Answer (score -1):

Check again your definitions of how $G$ acts on these things.

If $(\pi,V)$ is a representation of $G$, the contragredient representation $(\tilde{\pi}, V^{\ast})$ is given by

$$\tilde{\pi}(g)v^{\ast}(v) = v^{\ast}(\pi(g^{-1})v) \tag{$v^{\ast} \in V^{\ast}, v \in V$}$$

If $(\pi_1, V_1)$ and $(\pi_2,V_2)$ are two representations of $G$, the tensor product representation $\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2$ of $G$ on $V_1 \otimes V_2$ is given on generators by

$$\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2(g) \Big(v_1 \otimes v_2 \Big) = \pi_1(g)v_1\otimes \pi_2(g)v_2 $$

Finally $G$ acts on the space of linear maps $\operatorname{Hom}(V_1, V_2)$ by

$$\big[ g.\phi \big](v) = \pi_2(g) \phi\Big( \pi_1(g^{-1})v \Big) \tag{$\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}(V_1, V_2), v \in V_1$}$$